# iOS 6 deprecation of viewWillUnload & move to didReceiveMemoryWarning

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, didreceivememorywarning, viewdidunload

I'm  new developer about to launch my first app. I'm confused about the deprecation of `viewDidUnload` as described below in Apple's iOS 6 release notes:

> In iOS 6, the viewWillUnload and viewDidUnload methods of
>   UIViewController are now deprecated. If you were using these methods
>   to release data, use the didReceiveMemoryWarning method instead. You
>   can also use this method to release references to the view
>   controller’s view if it is not being used. You would need to test that
>   the view is not in a window before doing this.

Why is this happening? What guidelines should I follow to ensure that this change doesn't cause any performance issues in my app?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you currently using viewDidUnload for in your app?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to Apple, they have improved the internal memory management for views enough that the gains achieved by destroying stuff in `viewWill/DidUnload` are minimal.  Furthermore, they have data suggesting that many apps crash because the apps do not properly handle those notifications, and do "other" stuff not associated with the view unloading.

Finally, a memory warning is now verified as the first and only warning you will get before your app is terminated due to low memory, so it is really the place to handle memory issues.

So, basically, just remove your `viewWillUnload` and `viewDidUnload` methods.  Handle memory issues in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and any other view controller management in the appropriate places.

**EDIT**

> May I ask: what are those "appropiate places"? I used to use
>   ViewdidUnload in certain situations where view[Will/Did]Disappear were
>   not entirely adequate. Like going further down on the navigation
>   controller stack. Would you mind to elaborate further on that? –
>   Dan1one

That depends.  I know that's not what you want to hear, but it's the truth :-)

In general, you should avoid asymmetry.  Thus, you should "undo" an operation using the symmetric method from which you "did" the original.  In general, you should be able to do all the `viewDidUnload` type work in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and `dealloc`.

This should really not cause a change, because you had to duplicate most of that code in both of those places anyway.

I don't know what you mean by "going further down on the navigation controller stack" so you will need to clarify that example for me to provide a useful response.

One of the problems with using `viewDidDisappear` and `viewDidAppear` was that it was hard to know when the view was appearing because it was actually appearing, or because a view that was on top of it was disappearing... causing it to appear.

These pieces of API are supposed to help you address those issues:

```
- (BOOL)isMovingFromParentViewController
- (BOOL)isMovingToParentViewController
- (BOOL)isBeingDismissed
- (BOOL)isBeingPresented
```

Comment: May I ask: what are those "appropiate places"? I used to use ViewdidUnload in certain situations where view[Will/Did]Disappear were not entirely adequate. Like going further down on the navigation controller stack. Would you mind to elaborate further on that?

Comment: @Dan1one: umm... `viewDidUnload` is NOT called when being popped off the stack, or in most other circumstances. So I have no idea what you were doing

Comment: Greatest answer I saw for months. Thank you!

Comment: `In general, you should be able to do all the viewDidUnload type work in didReceiveMemoryWarning and dealloc`. So what are equivalent function for `viewWillUnload`?

Answer (score 8):

In iOS 6, views are never unloaded.

This means that `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` are only ever called once, and `viewDidUnload` is never called.  So if your view controller uses `viewDidUnload` to handle low memory conditions  then it will need to change.

If you want to respond to low memory conditions, implement `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and release your temporary data and objects in this method.

Answer (score 6):

In iOS 6 we should release views by ourself, do something like this

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    if([self isViewLoaded] && self.view.window == nil)
    {
        self.view = nil;
    }
}
```